# mPDF error dejavuserifcondensed.mtx.php No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

Can someone help me with this I am getting the following message when trying to use MPDF

```
include(/var/www/myapplication/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/ttfontdata/dejavuserifcondensed.mtx.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I have chmod'ed the correct files `ttfontdata`

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data     102 Aug 13 14:11 ttfontdata/
```

It seems like the system has to generate the files but its not.

Thanks,

Comment: How **`vendor directory`** is inside in your **`app directory`** something must be wrong?

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA my miss typo I edited. Do you have another idea ?

Comment: I think you should give full permission to vendor directory **`sudo chmod 777 -R vendor`** run this from your **`app root`** to give it a full permission and check if it's working or not?

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA I try but got the same error. `drwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   1224 Aug 13 15:38 vendor/`

Comment: Can you check this solution http://www.mpdf1.com/forum/discussion/2370/integrating-mpdf-with-laravel-5/p1

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA not work I checked before ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by using mPDF version 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

**mPDF** creates helper file `fontname.mtx.php` and saves there an absolute path of the font.

This causes trouble when you make some changes to the project directory structure.

#### Workaround

Just delete these helper files.

#### Note

I had the same problem with **tfpdf**.